# turn 2D logo into 3D voxel logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, pixelation

I have a 2D logo that I would like to make into a 3D "voxelized" logo. This website shows exactly what I mean...

- http://www.drububu.com/miscellaneous/voxelizer/index.html
- http://www.drububu.com/animation/lego/index.html

... it turns an ordinary image into a voxelized image...

[image]

... however, the downside is that I need to provide a 3D model for it to render. Instead, I'd like to know if there are resources out there to turn a logo into a voxelized 3D version. Are there special Photoshop/Illustrator effects that can assist me in this? Is there software out there that can extrude a 2D vector into a 3D model and voxelize it automatically?

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Thanks,
Hristo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voxels are by definition 3 dimensional elements but your graphic has no 3 dimensional information to it. You will need to somehow define 3D information for your shapes.

One simple approach would be to import your vector image into a 3D tool (3ds max, Maya, Blender, etc.) and extrude the shape. However the 3D model generated this way may not look like what you intend. Specifically, it will look like a cookie-cutter of your logo pushed onto a flat surface.

If the look you want is more like rounded blobs, well that is much more complicated to do. There isn't really an easy way to accomplish that, it requires some non-trivial work to model.

Comment: yeah... I started playing with Blender today and I accomplished just what I wanted. I was hoping for an easier solution :/

Comment: I have seen 3D-from-2D tools like Teddy or Archipelis but I'm not sure if any can import vectors: http://www.dailycupoftech.com/2008/08/24/teddy-3d-art-from-2d-drawings/ --- http://www.archipelis.com/

Comment: @jhocking Teddy (actually found [here](http://www-ui.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~takeo/teddy/teddy/teddy.html)) unfortunately seems defunct, but [Archipelis](http://www.archipelis.com) looks promising. And affordable... https://alternativeto.net/software/archipelis-designer/ might be worth a look as well

Answer (score 1):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org) will let you [import a path](http://hypertransitory.com/blog/2010/06/23/getting-your-adobe-illustrator-paths-into-blender-3d/) or [create a path](http://www.blendercookie.com/2009/05/20/modeling-with-curves/) that you can extrude into 3D. Once you have the model you should be able to use the link you posted to voxelize your object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like [this](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=convert+png+to+dxf) or [this](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=convert+png+to+obj). Converting the file might be the best solution. I tried tinkering around in photoshop and illustrator but there doesn't seem to be much native support for it. There could also be plug-ins or such available for either program that might also do something similar.

Comment: cheeky links, plus you're assuming he's starting with a raster image but his reference to Illustrator suggests vectors

Comment: His post refers to either photoshop or illustrator. And you can save raster images from illustrator. I didn't mean to be cheeky, but I guess I can understand how it could be seen as so. I personally always laugh when someone links me through that site.

Comment: Yeah I laugh at them too, but http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77377/ban-lmgtfy-links-across-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: Easy fix. Sorry if I offended anyone. Wasn't my intention.